# XmlMapper not escaping the greater-than character, but does escape the rest

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I'm using Jackson to serialize a POJO into an XML string. Here's an example of the object I'm trying to serialize

```
//A container class `container`
public class ContainerClass{
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ListOfItems")
    private List<Item> list;
}


//The class of the Object that's causing the issue
public class Item {
    private String Value;
    private EnumOfItemTypes ItemType; //enum has @JsonProperty() for each value

    public Item() {
        //Here's an example of the text contained in `value`
        this.value = "<<some place holder>> that uses " + 
                     "reserved xml characters & is actually " +
                     "what is causing the problem";
        this.ItemType = EnumOfItemTypes.100;
    }
}
```

### Problem

I am using this code here to serialize the object into an XML:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

public class main {
    SomeClass rootObject = new SomeClass();
    //bla bla, initialize rootObject with above value in a Container object

    XmlMapper xmlMapper = XmlMapper.builder().defaultUseWrapper(false).build();
    String dataXML = xmlMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(rootObject);
    system.out.println(dataXML);
}
```

Right now, the output I get looks something like this:

```
<rootObject>
    <container>
        <Value>
            &lt;&lt;some place holder>> that uses reserved 
            xml characters &amp; is actually what is causing the problem
        </Value>
        <ItemType>
            100
        </ItemType>
    </container>
</rootObject>
```

So both the ampersand and the lesser-than characters are escaped, but not the greater-than characters

### Questions

In XML, if no tag is opened with `<`, is it technically okay for `>` to be a part of the value?

If it ***may*** cause a problem, I'd much rather being able to force Jackson to also escape the `>` character, so how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If it could cause a problem Jackson, or any other proper XML library, would have escaped it. The greater-than character doesn't need escaping in XML. The less-than character on the other hand could be interpreted as opening an element, so it needs escaping.

Comment: awesome, that's what I was thinking, but I was still not sure. thanks

Comment: Many tools DO escape `>`, but it actually only needs to be escaped when it is part of the sequence `]]>`.